# Ansible Subversion Revision Export issue

Tags: svn, ansible, revision

I'm fairly new to Ansible but have got a fairly comprehensive playbook for our sites initial setup for new customers or for redeploying a customer site.

Ansible Revision = 2.0.0.2

Host = Ubuntu 16.04 up to date

Remote Host = CentOS 7 up to date from minimal install

The latter is where I'm having an issue, I export out of our SVN repo and this works fine.

```
name: Export from subversion
subversion: repo=svn+ssh://svnserver/file/path/svn/repo/trunk dest={{site_dir}} username=svn export=True
```

When I add

```
name: Export from subversion
subversion: repo=svn+ssh://svnserver/file/path/svn/repo/trunk dest={{site_dir}} username=svn export=True revision={{svn_rev}}
```

I get this error:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489135585.97-151625467432517/subversion\", line 2194, in \r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489135585.97-151625467432517/subversion\", line 231, in main\r\n    svn.export(force=force)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489135585.97-151625467432517/subversion\", line 149, in export\r\n    self._exec(cmd)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489135585.97-151625467432517/subversion\", line 127, in _exec\r\n    rc, out, err = self.module.run_command(bits, check_rc)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489135585.97-151625467432517/subversion\", line 2019, in run_command\r\n    args = [ os.path.expandvars(os.path.expanduser(x)) for x in args ]\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py\", line 261, in expanduser\r\n    if not path.startswith('~'):\r\nAttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

Now if I enter the revision manually save `revision=7840` it works as expected.

Also if I debug the variable

```
debug: msg={{svn_rev}}
```

It again outputs the correct revision.

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as I am a little bit stumped at the moment. Is this likely to be a bug with the subversion module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module clearly expects a string value, so define `svn_rev` as a string:

```
vars:
  svn_rev: "7840"
```

Or convert it to a string.

You have not specified in the question how you get the value, so you need to follow up yourself.

---

You might also consider filling an issue or PR on GitHub, because a common sense would be to convert the value inside the module.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure I had tried that already and failed to mention it in my post but obviously I didn't because it worked.

Comment: I will file an issue and also maybe an issue on the documentation to make it a bit clearer. Thanks again.